# Python incorrect answer input

Tags: python

I would like to make it so my menu works in a way which if a letter is input or anything other than a correct answer is input my script doesn't just end abruptly and it asks to input a correct option. Could anyone help me do this please? Here is the code i have so far:

```
#variables for password entry
secret_word = "giraffe"
guess = ""
guess_count = 0
guess_limit = 3
out_of_guesses = False

#password entry code
while guess != secret_word and not(out_of_guesses):
    if guess_count < guess_limit:
        guess = input("enter guess: ")
        guess_count += 1
    else:
        out_of_guesses = True

if out_of_guesses:
    print("out of guesses!")
else:
    print("You are into the secret lair!")

#Menu code

def menu(menu):
    print("--------------------------\nMenu\n--------------------------\n1.Secret 
Sauce\n2.More secret stuff\n3.Even more secret stuff\n4.Exit")
    choice = int(input("--------------------------\nENTER CHOICE: "))
     if choice == 1:
        print("--------------------------\nSecret Sauce recipe:\n1.ITS A SECRET!")
    elif choice == 2:
        print("--------------------------\nThis is also secret! Go away!")
    elif choice == 3:
    print("--------------------------\nYOU DARE TO TRY AGAIN?! STOP, GO AWAY!")
    elif choice > 4:
     print("This was not an option! TRY AGAIN!")
        return (menu)
    else:
        return(False)
    return(choice)

#exit loop for the def

running = True
while running:
    menuChoice = menu(menu)
    if menuChoice == False:
        print("\nGoodbye")
        running = False
```

Comment: This takes a number of different inputs; which are you referring to?

Comment: The menu part sorry, at the minute if i put in a letter for example and not a number it will just error and the script will end. I want it to send a response such as 'please enter a valid option' if an incorrect response is given to the menu input. Hope that makes sense?

Comment: @eescence I see, I've just provided an answer below. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `menu()` function,

Instead of immediately casting the input into an `int`, you can use a `try` statement to make sure the input is an integer, so if the user types in a letter your program will not stop. For example:

```
validInput = False
while validInput == False:
    choice = input("--------------------------\nENTER CHOICE: ")
    try:
        choice = int(choice)
        validInput = True
    except:
        print("Please enter an integer.")
```

Replace `choice = int(input("--------------------------\nENTER CHOICE: "))` with the above code and it will work.

Comment: Thank-you so much! This is amazing! I am still learning Python, I hope in the future i can think of something like this myself!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of
`choice = int(input("--------------------------\nENTER CHOICE: "))`

You can do the following:
`choice = input("--------------------------\nENTER CHOICE: ")`

and then after it we need to check if the string is a digit, so you can transfer it to "int" type safely.

```
if choice.isdigit():
    if choice == 1:
        print("--------------------------\nSecret Sauce recipe:\n1.ITS A SECRET!")
    elif choice == 2:
        print("--------------------------\nThis is also secret! Go away!")
    elif choice == 3:
        print("--------------------------\nYOU DARE TO TRY AGAIN?! STOP, GO AWAY!")
    elif choice > 4 or choice != (1,2,3,4):
        print("This was not an option! TRY AGAIN!")
    return (menu)
else:
    return(False)
return(choice)
```